# STM32U575 Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol SECURE_SystemCoreClockUpdate (referred from system_stm32u5xx_ns.o)

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, keil, nucleo

I'm trying to get started with a NUCLEO-U575ZI-Q board using STM32U575 MCU, but I'm not able to compile in Keil uvision 5 due to the following error:

.\Objects\test.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol SECURE_SystemCoreClockUpdate (referred from system_stm32u5xx_ns.o).
Not enough information to list image symbols.
Not enough information to list load addresses in the image map.
Finished: 2 information, 0 warning and 1 error messages.
".\Objects\test.axf" - 1 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:00

I have the latest version of Keil 5.38a, and I have installed the device support package for STM32U5xx.

[Keil compiler image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzv5t.png)

I think what is happening here is that one of the source files is missing. In the installation directory of Keil there is a file named "system_stm32u5xx_s.c" which contains all functionality for SECURE_SystemCoreClockUpdate() [CODE Snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Tja.png), [CODE Snippet_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WCGa.png). For some reason this file seems to not exist in my workspace at all. I'm not sure how to add it exactly.